# Multiple check box not working Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4.1.6

I am trying to create ability to select at least 3 services and then save with advertisement.

Model structure is like this:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :advertisement
end

class Advertisement < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :services
end
```

My form:

```
  <% @services.each do |service| %>
      <li>
        <%= check_box_tag 'service_ids[]', service.id -%>
        <%= h service.name -%>
      </li>
  <% end %>
```

Controller:

```
  class AdvertisementsController < ApplicationController


        before_action :authenticate_user!
      before_action :set_advertisement, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
     respond_to :html, :xml, :json

      def index
        @advertisements = Advertisement.all
       respond_with(@advertisements)
      end

      def show
         @advertisement = Advertisement.find(params[:id])
        respond_with(@advertisement)
      end

      def new
        @advertisement = Advertisement.new
        @services = Service.all
       respond_with(@advertisement)
      end

      def edit
      end


      def create
      @advertisement = Advertisement.new(advertisement_params)
        if @advertisement.save
         if params[:images]

             params[:images].each { |image|
               @advertisement.pictures.create(image: image)
            }
             respond_with(@advertisement)
          end

        else
          format.html { render 'new'} ## Specify the format in which you are rendering "new" page
          format.json { render json: @advertisement.errors } ## You might want to specify a json format as well
        end
      end

      def update
        @advertisement.update(advertisement_params)
      respond_with(@advertisement)
      end

      def destroy
        @advertisement.destroy
        respond_with(@advertisement)
      end

      private
        def set_advertisement
          @advertisement = Advertisement.find(params[:id])
        end

        def advertisement_params
          params.require(:advertisement).permit(:name, :user_id, :advertisement_id, :image,:terms_of_service,:region, :age, :height, :phone_number,:description)
        end
    end
```

When I check multpile services and click save there is no error. When I checked log files i got this message "

```
Parameters: ... "service_ids"=>["1", "2", "3"] ...
```

But then in console I check:

```
2.1.3 :008 >t = Advertisement.last (ALL OK)
....
    2.1.3 :008 > t.services

 => #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>
```

And this is error. Problem in associations, but everyrhing seems ok to me.

What could be the problem? 
Thanks

Comment: Where is the error? Your last code block is not problematic. How are you saving the services on the ad?

Comment: Have you allowed the service_ids in `advertisement_params` method or whatever you called it in your controller?

Comment: @japed I have allowed :service_id

Comment: you need the plural, and to show tell it to expect an array - `params.require(:advertisement).permit(service_ids: [])` did you define it like this?

Comment: @japed Igot this error `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ...ame, service_ids: [], :user_id, :advertisement_id, :image,:t... ... ^`

Comment: @EdgarsRozenfelds: You need to show complete form, controller, and model(if using nested attributes) code, it's hard to understand what you're exactly trying to do with the code you've posted currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no `service_ids` in `advertisement_params`. Add them:

```
@advertisement = Advertisement.new(advertisement_params.merge(service_ids: params[:service_ids]))
# or
@advertisement = Advertisement.new(advertisement_params)
@advertisement.service_ids = service_ids
```